# User thread vs. Kernel thread

Tags: multithreading

I didn't quite understand the difference between threads in kernel space and threads in user space.
Could you kindly explain the difference to me in simple terms? Perhaps with a practical example.

Comment: See [AIX: kernel threads, user threads](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=processes-kernel-threads-user-threads).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest terms, the difference is scheduling.

The kernel always schedules which apps run on which CPU(s).

In user threads the kernel sees your app as one "thread" and schedules it on a CPU. The user thread library then slices that time up between the user threads (on the single CPU given by the kernel scheduler).

In kernel threads the kernel sees your app as many threads and can schedule them to spread among the available CPUs.

Comment: This is not the type of question to answer here.